# How to + the values in two lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I add the tuples from two lists of tuples to get a new list of the results?

For example:

```
a = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]   
b = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
```

We want to get

```
c = [(2,2),(4,4),(6,6)]
```

I searched google and found many results how to simply add two lists together using zip, but could not find anything about two lists of tuples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `zip` twice and a list comprehension:

```
In [63]: a = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]

In [64]: b = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]

In [66]: [tuple(map(sum, zip(x, y))) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
Out[66]: [(2, 2), (4, 4), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: This is a nice way of solving the problem if you don't know how many elements are in each tuple ahead of time.  +1

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
>>> b = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
>>> [(i[0]+j[0], i[1]+j[1]) for i, j in zip(a,b)]
[(2, 2), (4, 4), (6, 6)]
```